# Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent: Server and Database

Tags: sql-server, synchronization, agent

I'm struggling with Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent, which I need to setup the windows Azure platform. 
In the ms sql data sync agent preview, the "Ping Sync Service" is successfully executed.
My windows firewall is allowing ingoing via port 1433.

The problem is, when I want to "Register":
First, I'm not sure that I enter the correct "Server" and "Database" names.
Second, I'm not sure whether I should use "SQL" or "Windows" Authentication
Third, how do I ensure that the Client Sync Agent has appropriate rights to the database?

Among alot of other trials, my best guess is: 
Server " .\SQLEXPRESS"
Database "SiteSqlServer"

but still I get the following 2 error messages:

1) Unable to connect to the Database. PLease check if service account has connectivity, credentials and permissions to connect. Server: "XXX\SQLEXPRESS". Database: "SiteSqlServer".

2) Connection faild. Please check database credentials along with permissions for Microsoft SQL Data Sync Windows service logon account to connect to database with specified credentials. 
Other reasons for failure:
Windows Azure SQL databases have to be added on the SQL Data Sync portal. 
SQL Server databases lower than SQL Server 2005 SP2 are not supported on the SQL Data Sync.

I'm using: dotnetnuke CMS system and Microsoft webmatrix.

Any idea on how to proceed from here is warmly welcomed!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm no Azure expert so this isn't an answer, but have you created a database on the server?  I.e., is there a SiteSqlServer database there? SQL versus Windows authentication depends on whether you've created a login in sql server, or if you're trying to authenticate just through windows (no login box, it just knows who you are). I would start by creating a login with the sysadmin role and see if that works, then start removing rights until it has the bare minimum to make your application work.

Comment: when you installed the agent, what account did you specify as the service account? did you check that account if it has permission on the database? the choice of using Windows or SQL Authentication depends on how you setup your authentication on the SQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to sync SQL Azure with SQL Express which is not supported and not tested. That's why when you try as described above you get that error. Based on my experiences there are issues using with SQL Express and SQL DataSync and SQL Express is not listed helow:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh456371.aspx

There are a few articles on internet where a few folks who went ahead and hacked the system to work with some vers'on of SQL Express so you are your own if you wish to try further. An article I found is [here](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/sql-azure-data-sync-service-sql-express-and-sql-express-2012-localdb/):

Comment: there is no hacking required to make SQL Azure Data Sync Service work with SQL Express. it should work out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @JuneT. Do you have some documentation on how to get it done? I have had a few more person face same problem and only using on-premise SQL server and SQL Azure could work. It would be great to have documentation on how to do it correctly...

Comment: as I have mentioned, there is no hack. you configure it in the same way you configure SQL Server. internally, SQL Azure Data Sync uses Sync Framework and uses the SQLSyncProvider (an extended one), the same provider use with SQL Express, SQL Local DB, SQL Server and SQL Azure.